# How to check the current node while iterating though nodes in Xml?

Tags: java, xml

I have to load values in a combo-box based on the values in the xml.

When I the combo-box is to be loaded, the method

```
public static List<String> getVariableNames(Element thisElement, String type) {

    if (thisElement == null) {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    List<String> variableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Element> variableElements = thisElement.elements();
    for (Element nextElement : variableElements) {
        if (thisElement.equals(nextElement)) {
            break;
        } else if (isVariable(nextElement)) {
            String iteratedType = nextElement.attributeValue("TYPE");
            if (type.equals(iteratedType)) {
                variableNames.add(nextElement.attributeValue("VARIABLENAME"));
            }
        }
    }
    return variableNames;
}
```

is called.

But this is not working.

Is there any problem in this implementation?

Comment: have you tried debugging and see where is it failing ?

Comment: It is actually not failing. As per the code (if it is right), the for loop will break when the `thisElement` becomes  equal to `nextElement` , it should understand that the current node has reached. But it is not working at that if condition.

Comment: What XML API are you using. What does the `elements()` method returns?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, thisElement.equals(nextElement) always returns false.

**Possible Reason :**

`thisElement` and `nextElement` may be references to different objects (although with the same content), the default implementation of .equals() compares the addresses of the objects which may be different in this case.

Please make sure that `equals()` method is actually implemented  by the Element class and compares the required fields so that it returns true for equal/same objects.

Comment: as you told it the `equals()` method is comparing both the objects. so how can I get the current element object in the xml tree to compare while iterating through xml tree.

Comment: the return value of thisElement.elements() is not clear by looking at the code. Please explain this and then I may be able to further investigate.

Comment: `thisElement.elements()` returns a List of elements or child nodes under a particular node or element.

Comment: If it returns the childNodes, thisElement.equals(nextElement) will always return false as nextElement is a childNode and you are comparing parent element to child elements.

Comment: Yes, u r rite.. Trying to do it in another way.. Will keep posted.